# Known approaches for the lower bound on cap-set problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $r(n):=r_3(\mathbb{F}_3^n)=\max\{|A|: A \subset \mathbb{F}_3^n, \ A \text{ is 3-AP-free}\}$.

[Edel](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1027365901231) proved that $r(n)\geq 2.217^n$ for sufficiently large $n$. His proof is by giving a construction of a cap-set $A$ in $\mathbb{F}_3^{480}$. Then observing that $A^k \subset \mathbb{F}_3^{480k}$ is also a cap set, that is,
$$r(480k)\geq |A^k|=|A|^k.$$

Is this the best known lower bound? Are there other known approaches to this problem other than construction in low dimension and then using this product argument?

Is this product argument expected to be the best we could expect? That is, do we hope to construct an $A$ such that this argument is tight?

I'd appreciate any references or answers to some of these questions.

Any help on the tags or on how to better ask these questions would be nice also.

Comment: I think it's an open problem whether blowing up an example could yield a tight bound.

Comment: See Remark 6.2.10 of https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ashj34jk6i905n/AAAhThbmPXvJcYOHS0IU2cQJa/gtacbook.pdf (draft of book by Yufei Zhao on graph theory and additive combinatorics). It claims Edel's is the best published lower bound.

Comment: I'll promote my paper with Kleinberg and Sawin https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00047 . We construct a lower bound for the colored version (which is easier than the original version) which exactly matches the upper bound coming from the polynomial method of Ellenberg and Gijswijt.

Comment: I am pessimistic about adopting our method to the non-colored cap set problem; see Remark 7 in our paper for why. I have wondered whether there might be some way to instead use Remark 7's ideas to improve the Ellenberg and Gijswijt bound, but I haven't found a way.

Comment: Here is a related question: what is the reason for the absence of a Behrend-type construction in this setting?

Comment: Our paper can roughly be summarized as "map $F_3^n$ to $F_P$ for a large prime $P \approx 3^n$ and use a Behrend construction in $F_P$." From this perspective, the $\theta^n$ term bound of Ellenberg-Gijswijt comes from the inefficiency of the $F_3^n \to F_P$ construction. (I can say more if you like.) So one answer is that Ellenberg-Gijswijt is measuring the inadequacy of the heuristic that $F_3^n$ is like $F_P$ for $P \approx 3^n$. @SamHopkins

Comment: Edel's bound seems to be the best one presently known, but there are "algebraic" constructions which also give nontrivial bounds. We can only speculate whether the largest capsets come from blowing up some particular example.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thanks! I'll definitely take a deeper look into it.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that in Edel's paper are more sophisticated ways of leveraging small cap sets into larger ones than just the direct product argument (basically a sort of 'twisted' product instead).

Comment: If any method gives an asymptotic of $c^n$ for the cap-set problem, then by specializing it to a particular value of $n$ and taking products of that, you can get $(c-\epsilon)^n$ for any $n$. Since products can never be too far behind, it should maybe not be surprising when (twisted) products are ahead.

Comment: @SamHopkins Behrend's construction relies on a specific progression-free set in $\mathbb R^n$, the sphere. Using base notation, you can approximate a large chunk of $\mathbb Z/N$, $n$ large, by $[0,\dots, b/2]^n \subset \mathbb R^n$, and take a sphere in that, then, crucially, optimize $b$ and $n$. In $\mathbb F_3^n$ we don't have an analogue of base notation except in the special case $b=3$, which is not optimal, so we can't apply the same construction.

Comment: Alternately you could say we're working in $\mathbb F_3[t]$ and then can work in base $b$ when $b$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. But then the set of "digits" is $\mathbb F_3^b$, and we have returned to the same problem. So the characteristic 3 structure of $\mathbb F_3^n$ makes it harder to approximate with $\mathbb Z^n$ and then with $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with @WillSawin's claim that the ability to optimize $b$ is crucial. In my opinion, the key issue is that many $3$-AP's in $\mathbb{F}_3^n$ don't lift to $3$-AP's in $\{ 0,1,2 \} \subset \mathbb{Z}$. For example, $(1,0,2)$ is an AP modulo $3$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$. I think you should be able to make subsets of $\{ 0,1,2 \}^n$ of size $(3-o(1))^n$ which are $3$-AP free by taking a random linear map $\{ 0,1,2 \}^n \to \mathbb{Z}/P \mathbb{Z}$ and discarding collisions, as in our paper. I think I might leave an answer about this tonight.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer One doesn't need to use randomness for that problem. For $\{0,1,2\}^n$, one can simply take all solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)^2 =  2n/3$, or something like that, to find sets of size $3^n/\sqrt{n}$. The Behrend approach Is to restrict to the subset of $\{0,\dots \frac{b-1}{2} \}$, which doesn't have the problem you mention where there are 3-APs that don't lift, but this introduces a loss that shrinks as $b$ grows, which forces you to take $b$ large if you want to optimize.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I didn't quite understand how Remind 7 indicates this idea couldn't work in the uncoloured setting. I understand that a 3-AP-free set "induces" a symmetric tricoloured 3-AP-free set. On the other hand, tricoloured sum-set "induces" a assymmetric tricoloured 3-AP-free set... Can you develop a little bit more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just proved a new lower bound of $2.218^n$, in my paper 'New lower bounds for cap sets': https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10045.

My new bound comes from extending Edel's ideas, with better computational methods (including a SAT solver) and introducing a new theoretical construction. I also conjecture that a lower bound of $2.233^n$ is possible, which is explained in section 4 of my paper.

My lower bound comes from a cap set in $\mathbb{F}_3^{56232}$, although I do also give cap sets in 396, 420 and 462 dimensions which beat Edel (slight correction to your post: Edel's bound comes from a cap set in $\mathbb{F}_3^{480}$).